# How to Get HTTP Status Code using OkHttp without Loading the Entire Response First

Tags: okhttp

I'm attempting to make a GET request using OkHttp library in my Android App. I need to get the response code only and not the entire response body.

```
val response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I know I can use the `response.code()` method to obtain the status code but the execute method doesn't complete unless the response is fully downloaded. I need to proceed step by step.

Comment: You can get the status code without downloading the whole response body. The response body  is streamed.

Comment: @JesseWilson but it seems the `execute` method is synchronous and doesn't return until `Response` is loaded. Perhaps I'm missing something here.